# How to upload images from internal storage to server using Retrofit?

Tags: android, file, upload, retrofit, internal-storage

I'm trying to upload two images from internal storage of my android device to HTTP-server.

```
    public interface ApiService {
        ...

        @Multipart
        @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
        @POST("signature/{id}")
        Call<String> sendSignature(
                @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                @Path("id") String id,
                @Part("descrtipion") RequestBody description,
                @Part MultipartBody.Part file1,
                @Part MultipartBody.Part file2);
    }

...


private void sendSignatures(){
    RequestBody description = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, getString(R.string.str_file_description));

    File file2 = getFileStreamPath(SIGNATURE2_PATH);
    RequestBody requestFile2 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), file2);
    MultipartBody.Part body2 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("sign1", file2.getName(), requestFile2);

    File file = getFileStreamPath(SIGNATURE_PATH);
    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("sign2", file.getName(), requestFile);

    Call<String> call = ApiFactory.getService().sendSignature(token, PARAMETER_ID, description, body2, body);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) Log.d("myLogs", "Yes: " + response.body());
            else Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ErrorUtils.errorMessage(response), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

But server returns error #500. At the same time request from Postman is successful (#200).

Please, help me to fix it: where do I make a mistake in java-code?

Comment: If the server is returning #500 means its "crashing". Try to get the log see what extra params are getting or getting modified at the server end.

Comment: responce, coming from server, has empty body. but Postman successes, sending files. maybe "File file2 = getFileStreamPath(SIGNATURE2_PATH);" is not valid for accessing files from internal storage?

Comment: code 500 means that there is something wrong with the server. It is true that you might be sending something not the way the server expects, but you have to ask the server developer what exactly is wrong.

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko but to send POST-request from Postman or another API-testing program is possible. I'm surprised too, but it is a fact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Particularly in this case it was necessary to remove header:

```
public interface ApiService {
    ...

    @Multipart
    @POST("signature/{id}")
    Call<String> sendSignature(
            @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
            @Path("id") String id,
            @Part("descrtipion") RequestBody description,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part file1,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part file2);
}
```

When I tried to send this request through Postman and put only one file, or two files, one or both with wrong keys, even if token was incorrect, server passed #500 error. So first of all they check keys and files, and then - authorization parameter. I removed header and in this case got successful responce.